# Best way to insulate wash room ceiling?

Tags: insulation

I have a washroom that’s attached to our house. When we remodeled, we insulated all the walls with rockwool but have not finish the ceiling. It is 2 x 6 with a TPO roof above. We are in season 5 zone.

What would be the best way to insulate this, and do I have to allow for venting with an air gap above the insulation? [[image: p][1]]

[image]

Comment: Are you just interested in insulating, or also finishing the ceiling in some manner?

Comment: You must have some kind of glue-down roofing material?

Comment: With plumbing, you'd not want it to room to drop below freezing! What heating is supplied to the room? My own choice would be to use glass fiber bats above a glass fiber-based drop ceiling, for ease of installation and a bit more insulation, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: I sometimes run a small space heater in winter as my water mains are in here. I do plan on finishing the ceiling with t&g